# Can i remove Recall option in Approval process?

Tags: approval-process

I want to remove Recall option provided on salesforce native page and want to use my own custom button for that in Approval process.

Answer (score 3):

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/approvals_recall_actions.htm

This option of recall is available only if you have  checked  the checkbox "allow the submitter to recall".If you uncheck the recall button won't appear.

And putting your own custom button will imply you may need to write your own approval process using apex classes for approval process.

Comment: By doing this will my custom button works or not, on which i have used apex class for approval process

Comment: @Pankaj Surely it will work for you.Custom button once you have you can use this for your custom created approval flow